# Filesystem local storage can't display image in Laravel

Tags: laravel, filesystems, local-storage, laravel-5.3

Hi i have a problem with displaying images after uploading his to the storage path.

Code for upload files is

```
                //Get a file
                $file = $request->file('post_thumbnail');

                //Get a file extension
                $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

                //Save a file
                $request->file('post_thumbnail')->storeAs('uploads/post/postThumbnail', $post->id.'.'.$ext, 'public');
```

Everything is saved okay, but i can't display this images, i getting error in console - file not found.
I tried everything what i could did but sometimes is display nothing or little square, but never image. I tried display it with Storage::get, Storage::url, and manually put path to the file, could someone show me how i should display images?

Comment: is the image upload to serve ? image in side this folder
uploads/post/postThumbnail

Comment: Yes, files is uploaded, but i can't display them, file is in this path.

Comment: can you told me how you want to display it .

Comment: can you try to display image with this 
<img  src="{{  asset("uploads/post/postThumbnail/image.jpg") }}">

Comment: asset not working for me, i see little square.

I tried like that:
Storage::get('app/public/uploads/post/postThumbnail/image.png')
or
Storage::url('app/public/uploads/post/postThumbnail/image.png')
or
Storage::disk('public')->get('uploads/post/postThumbnail/image.png')
or
Storage::disk('public')->url('app/public/uploads/post/postThumbnail/image.png')
or
<img src="{!! storage_path . 'link_to_file' !!}">